How to add support for JXL on Loupe (GNOME's Image Viewer)
I have some photos with the .jxl filename extension. They are in the new image format known as JPEG-XL.
I have installed GNOME's new image viewer program named Loupe or Image Viewer in Ubuntu 24.10, like this:
sudo apt install loupe

(Loupe is an alternative to the older GNOME program known as Eye of GNOME)
When I open a JPEG-XL file, I get this error:

Could not Load Image
The image format "JPEG XL image (image/jxl)" is known but not installed.

How do I install support for JPEG XL in Loupe?


As you can see in the Ubuntu source code for glycin-loaders, Debian has disabled the support for JPEG XL and Ubuntu uses the same package.
The only solution I can offer is to use the Flatpak version of Loupe that is supported by me, the maintainer of Loupe, and comes with JPEG XL support.

Thank you for maintaining Loupe! That's good news that the Flatpak version of Loupe supports JXL. I don't know why Debian patched out JXL support. As it turns out, the snap version of Loupe packaged by Canonical also doesn't support JXL, so the Flatpak version is the best bet.

@Flimm the initial commit from last year says "The JPEG-XL feature will be enabled once it's been stabilized", so maybe if it is stable now, you can ask the maintainer to enable it.
